# How to global import a stylus file in vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, stylus

Now I'm try use `vite` to create a `vue` app.
But have trouble to global import a `stylus` file in `vite.config.js`.

I try the code from vite docs.

```
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      styl: {
        additionalData: `@import "./src/assets/styles/common.styl"`
      }
    }
  }
})
```

But it's completely not work.

I got a solution to set global style from github.

```
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      stylus: {
        globals: {
          '$highlight-color': 'red'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

It's works fine, But how to import a styl file globaly?
I tried to add 'additionalData' to the workable config. However I got bunch of errors: 'failed to locate file'. It seems like try to import the file in every .vue file, but has trouble to locate the file.

```
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      stylus: {
        additionalData: `@import "./src/assets/styles/common.styl";`,
        globals: {
          '$color-g1': '#F3F4FC',
          '$color-white': '#FFFFFF',
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Have any idea about this?

Comment: Your import path looks incorrect (don't use `./src` in your import paths). It should be `@import "@/assets/styles/common.styl"`. And you should add an alias for `@` via `resolve.alias` in your Vite config.

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me:

```
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      stylus: {
        imports: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/styles/common.styl')],
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is accurate and gives result. It is also self-explanationary.